# Firebase Auth using Flutter: how do I access user ID from onAuthStateChanged?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

New to Flutter and Firebase.
I would like to access the uid from the returned value of this getter:

```
  Stream<User> get isConnected {
    // this is equivalent to:
    // return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map((FirebaseUser user) => _userFromFirebase(user));
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFireBase);
  }
```

this is _userFromFireBase:

```
  User _userFromFireBase(FirebaseUser user) {
    User userObject = User(user: user.uid);
    // should return user id or null
    return user != null ? userObject : null;
  }
```

How do I go about it?

Comment: What's the problem when you run this code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen When I print the returned value of ```isConnected``` all I get is ```Instance of '_MapStream<FirebaseUser, User>'```

Comment: Given that it's a stream that seems correct. If you want to print the values in the stream, you can to is `listen()` to gets its individual values.